# Google's closure library giving some strange symbols using NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library, currency-formatting

I'm just trying to familiarise myself with the basics of this Library, just printing the result of the computation to the console. However when doing so, in more than one of the supported locales, the result is... interesting. In this example, instead of being £200.58 it is in fact Â£200.58 has anyone else encountered this?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>

    <script>
        goog.require('goog.i18n.NumberFormat');
    </script>

    <script>
        goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols = goog.i18n.NumberFormatSymbols_en_GB; 

        var formatter = new goog.i18n.NumberFormat(goog.i18n.NumberFormat.Format.CURRENCY);

        console.log(formatter.format(200.58));
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What character encoding is your page using?

Comment: UTF-8 As far as I'm aware! 
EDIT: Ah, the page set itself to Western which was causing the issue. Thanks for pointing that out to me!